# POST max size in nginix apache and php

Tags: php, apache, nginx, web

I have my setup as nginx acting as a proxy server and apache is configured with php.

I am sending a internal post request through curl onto my server. But the string length what i am sending id `4023` characters. But at the service I get only 1013 characters as string length.

I have checked my php.ini. I have `post_max_size` as `24M` that is sufficient.
In **nginx.conf**, I have set `client_max_body_size 8m`.

But still I am getting the trimmed content. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make changes in input_max_vars in php.ini or in .htaccess file.

```
php_value max_input_vars 2000
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: I updated php_value max_input_vars 10000 in httpd.conf, but still i am not able to get the data.

Comment: have you checked the same in phpinfo. if its taking 10000